# How to add multiple variables in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have an if/else clause in a list comprehension and would like to know how I can add multiple variables.

Here's is the code if I use a an if/else statement:

```
if start_year == end_year:
    years = [start_year]
else:
    years = [start_year, end_year]
```

Here's how I would like it to look with a list comprehension, however it is incorrect because it tacks on end_year due to the comma separation.

```
years = [start_year if start_year == end_year else start_year, end_year]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this need to be a list comprehension, or just a one-liner? This is pretty readable and avoids exceedingly fancy moves (and is very similar to your example): `years = [start_year] if start_year == end_year else [start_year, end_year]`

Comment: What result do you want instead?

Comment: A list comprehension is an idiom for "creating" lists and what your doing is a simple assignment based on a condition. you might need to give us more context.

Comment: Yea a one-liner is the most sensible approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if/else` can be consolidated into 1 line:

```
years = [start_year] if start_year == end_year else [start_year, end_year]
```

Note that this isn't a "list comprehension" though because there is no `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
years = [year for index, year in enumerate((start_year, end_year))
         if index == 0 or start_year != end_year]
```

As you wish... it's as ugly as a pig though.